# C# Missing title in MAUI app only Code, no XAML

Tags: c#, maui

I create a Example Maui app and delete pre-created XAML and AppShell files.

App.xaml.cs accordingly changed to MainPage()

```
namespace MauiApp1 {
    public partial class App : Application {
        public App() {

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs content

```
namespace MauiApp1 {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {

        public MainPage() {
            Title = "StackLayout Spacing demo";

            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(20),
                Spacing = 6
            };

            stackLayout.Add( new Label { Text = "Primary colors" } );
            stackLayout.Add( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Red, HeightRequest = 40 } );
            stackLayout.Add( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Yellow, HeightRequest = 40 } );
            stackLayout.Add( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Blue, HeightRequest = 40 } );
            stackLayout.Add( new Label { Text = "Secondary colors" } );
            stackLayout.Add( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Green, HeightRequest = 40 } );
            stackLayout.Add( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Orange, HeightRequest = 40 } );
            stackLayout.Add( new BoxView { Color = Colors.Purple, HeightRequest = 40 } );

            Content = stackLayout;
        }
    }

}
```

All is fine, but there is no Title visible, could you please tell me, what I did wrong? or how could I solve it?
[Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xISia.png)

I would like to see the title. I can I solve the problem of invisible title.

Comment: Did you try  this.Title = "StackLayout Spacing demo";

Comment: if you are not using a NavigationPage then there is no title bar for the title to appear in

Answer (score 1):

As Jason has pointed it out, you need to set the `MainPage` as [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-8.0) like below:

```
public App() 
{
     InitializeComponent();
     //set the root as NavigationPage
     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

So you can set its [Title](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page.title?view=net-maui-8.0#microsoft-maui-controls-page-title) property in code-behind:

> Gets or sets the page's title. (Inherited from [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page?view=net-maui-8.0))

**Output:**

[image]